# What did griffiths do here? Trig Identity for buffons needle

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

I'm on the very last part of the equation for buffons needle.  I think it's a trig identity, but I can't find it. Either way, I can give more info if needed but it looks like this.

[image: The answer]

Comment: I think we need more info about the condition of $y,l.$

Comment: It's the final integral, lots of math to get to this point, but it's to show that y can be anywhere along the line of l
He also said that for y to fall anywhere along the line of l would all be equal.  I'll see if I can write some more stuff down.

Comment: Okay, I just uploaded the entire solution....event though it was a 3 step question.

Comment: Ah, the fact being used is that, for any $t$,
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sin^{-1} t \, dt = \int_{0}^{1} \sin^{-1} (1-t) \,dt$$
Roughly, this is true because in both cases you're adding up the same values, just in a different order. With $t = \frac{y}{l}$, you get that the integrals of $\sin^{-1}(y/l)$ and of $\sin^{-1}((l-y)/y)$ are the same (both integrals from $0$ to $l$).

Comment: This seems an unnecessarily difficult way to solve the problem. I think it's much easier if you swap the order of integration. That is, instead of integrating over the vertical position last, integrate over the angle last. If the angle is $\theta$ (relative to the direction of the lines) the probability of a crossing is $\sin \theta$, so the answer is $\frac1\pi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta\,d\theta = 2/\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

The equality holds not because the integrands are necessarily equal, but because $$\int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{l-y}{l}\right) dy = \int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right)dy.\qquad (\ast)$$

Once you have this equality, then

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\pi l}\int_0^l\pi - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right) - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{l-y}{l}\right)dy\\ 
= &\frac{1}{\pi l}\left[\int_0^l\pi dy - \int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right)dy - \int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{l-y}{l}\right)dy\right]\\
= &\frac{1}{\pi l}\left[\int_0^l\pi dy - \int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right)dy - \int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right)dy\right]\\
= &\frac{1}{\pi l}\int_0^l\pi - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right) - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right)dy\\
= &\frac{1}{\pi l}\int_0^l\pi - 2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{l}\right)dy.
\end{align*}

To see why $(\ast)$ is true, let $z = l - y$ in the first integral, then we have $$\int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{l-y}{l}\right) dy = \int_l^0\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{l}\right)(-dz) = \int_0^l\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{l}\right)dz.$$ Replacing $z$ by $y$ gives the final result.

Comment: Wait...what?  Sorry.

Comment: @Dustin.: Both sides of $(\star)$ integrate the values of $\sin^{-1}$ between $0$ and $1$, just in opposite directions. The substitution double-checks that the opposite directions are compatible. (In contrast, $$\int_0^{1} \sin^{-1}x \;dx \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^{1} \sin^{-1}x^2 \;dx$$ both integrate the values of $\sin^{-1}$ between $0$ and $1$, but they don't move through those values at a compatible rate. (I'll note that "compatible" is my own descriptor here, not a formal term.))